# Body width can be can be overwritten?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is possible to override the body width, for example I have this ex.:

```
<body>
<table id="table1">
<tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
<table id="table2">
<tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
</body>

css:
body{width:970px;}
#table1{width:100%;}
#table2{width:100%;}
```

I want to set for first table a width:auto; expandable on full browser width but body width won't allow.

I must have that body:970px so I cannot modify that and I must have 100% for second table to expand all elements inside in 970px body width.

how do I resolve this ?

[**fiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vqmaw/2104/)

Comment: Never give width to the body. It's not a good practice

Comment: I would go with @sandeep and I also don't get the problem. If the first table has full width set it to 100% and the second set to 970px.

Comment: @sandeep unfortunately the app is already created by another developer I try to redesign a little bit old fashion, if I remove body width I' ruin entire app alignment :(

Comment: @insertusernamehere booth table has 100% width, the body width has 970px

Comment: I would have suggested something like Aaron answered. Remove the width from the body, place a div, that wraps all content that has to be 970px and than place the content that has to be 100% screen width outside that div. Ah, and my first comment was to meant in combination with what @sandeep said - so with removing the fixed body width. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no good way to do this; HTML elements always inherit attributes from their parents. So if you give `body` a fixed width, you essentially limit what the children can do. For them, the world (i.e. `width: 100%`) is now the limited `body` width and there is no way to say "use the parent width but skip the body element, please".

With JavaScript, you could try to get the width of the `html` element but even if you assigned this to `table1`, the overflow rules would probably clip it.

To fix this, you will have to get rid of the fixed body width. Replace body with a container `div` with a fixed width. That allows you to move `table1` outside the container `div` where it will see the `body`'s natural width.

Comment: yes this is the best answer, I'll "replace" body with a container div. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Because you say: I must have that body:970px so I cannot modify that, i guess you can not modify the body CSS:
you could do:

CSS

```
#table1, #table2 {width:970px;}
```

or

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('body').css('width', '970px');
})
```

Comment: This is a very bad answer there is no need for javascript here

Comment: he said: I must have that body:970px so I cannot modify that, that calls for a js solution, not?